# What does the single letter 'P' in email mean?

Tags: meaning, email

I notice that many of my emails have this single letter 'P' beside a sentence and that sentence is usually about protecting nature.

Example:

```
P Print Only When Necessary
```

What does the P mean? Is it just a typo error?

**Update**

The P is not "Please", it is a icon

The icon can be find under the letter P in the following link: 
http://speakingpowerpoint.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/symbol-fonts-full-page2.jpg

Comment: It's not part of standard English. Perhaps it's just a smiley like [this one asking about the letter 'J'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46829/what-does-a-single-letter-j-mean-in-emailing). If you get 'many' such emails, why not ask one of the people who sends them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like the link FumbleFingers posted, it's indeed a [graphic](http://thinkbeforeprinting.org/get-the-message.php), though not a smiley.

The capital P in the font *Webdings* appears to be a river through a field with a tree in the distance.  However, if you don't have the font installed or the font has been stripped (due to plain text emails or what have you) you just see *P*