# Expression: 'Correct! J'?

Tags: expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a single letter “J” mean in emailing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46829/what-does-a-single-letter-j-mean-in-emailing)

To q question that I had asked I got a reply as below:
Correct! J

Is there an expression like this in English.
Just to clarify, neither my name nor the sender's name has the alphabet *J* embedded. The sender's entire reply was as follows:

Correct! J
-Sender Name

Also, this does not appear to be a typo since this is the second time I received this reply.

Comment: Help me find the original question that makes this question an exact duplicate